# What particles existed in the Planck, GUT, and electroweak epochs, respectively?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, quarks, leptons, quark-gluon-plasma

What quarks, leptons, and bosons existed in each of the individual epochs of the early universe (Planck, GUT, electroweak)? Did the quantum zoo gain or lose species during these times? Or did some of the particles break down into smaller ones at any point in this timeline?

Comment: Symmetry breaking takes you from one type of gluon with many colors to many types of gluons each with a few colors. The number of species in this sense is preserved.

Comment: @ConnorBehan- What were those  gluons called? what fermions existed during those times?

Comment: Before electroweak symmetry breaking, the fermions were the same while the $Z$ and photon were called the $W_3$ and $B$. At the other scales, notation is less standard because of how many possible symmetry breaking patterns there are. No one has a good idea of which one is right yet.

Comment: see weinberg's book *the first three minutes*.

Comment: @nielsnielsen thank you. just spent an audible credit on it. 

Answer (score 1):

> What particles existed in the Planck, GUT, and electroweak epochs, respectively?

This depends on the cosmological model, because from GUTs on we are still examining data and observations in particle physics experiments in order to validate a specific mathematical model.

In electroweak breaking the existing theory keeps the group structure of the standard model of particle physics so, if nothing contrary is discovered experimentally the same number of particles should fill the quantum number positions before symmetry breaking , note that the masses are  zero.

In the [big bang ,model,](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Astro/timlin.html) this is the order of symmetry breaking

[image: timeline BB]

When one goes to [GUTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Unified_Theory), more particles are expected than the ones in the standard model, as there are lots of new quantum number locations to be fulfilled by a particle.

Planck epoch is just even more imaginary, open to all theories.

The holy grail is a unification of all forces in a quantum model. String theories can do that in a completely new way where the SU(n) symmetries become vibrations on [strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_theory) and membranes, and where [supersymmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersymmetry) would at least double the possible number of particles.

So the answer is: various models can be used and if rigorous mathematically can be tested against observations. Thus the field is open for theoretical research.